# hooked policies returns an empty array, sails

Tags: service, sails.js, hook, policies

im tryng to make works two hooked policies, but doesnt. Each of these works, and both return next(), but then, when it supposed pass to a controller, return it an empty array instead of the list of devices
Here's my config/policies.js

```
module.exports.policies = {

  '*': ['isAuthorized'], // Everything resctricted here
  'UserController': {
    'create': true // We dont need authorization here, allowing public access
  },

  'AuthController': {
    '*': true // We dont need authorization here, allowing public access
  },

  'device' : {
    'find' : ['isAuthorized', 'isOwner']
  }

};
```

this is my policies. policies/isAuthorized.js

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  var token;

  if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization) {
    var parts = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    if (parts.length == 2) {
      var scheme = parts[0],
        credentials = parts[1];

      if (/^Bearer$/i.test(scheme)) {
        token = credentials;
      }
    } else {
      return res.json(401, {err: 'Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]'});
    }
  } else if (req.param('token')) {
    token = req.param('token');
    // We delete the token from param to not mess with blueprints
    delete req.query.token;
  } else {
    return res.json(401, {err: 'No Authorization header was found'});
  }

  // aqui se consulta a la funcion verify del archivo jwToken.js q esta disponible dentro de services
  jwToken.verify(token, function (err, token) {
    if (err) return res.json(401, {err: 'Invalid Token!'});
    req.token = token; // This is the decrypted token or the payload you provided
    next();
  });
};
```

And policies/isOwner.js, which one is only a test for the moment

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  // User is allowed, proceed to the next policy,
  // or if this is the last policy, the controller
  if (req.param('pass') == 'secret') {
    return next();
  }

  // User is not allowed
  // (default res.forbidden() behavior can be overridden in `config/403.js`)
  return res.forbidden('You are not permitted to perform this action.');
};
```

I hope for your helpfull and sorry for my bad english.